# Which is preferred: 'long int' or 'long'

Tags: c, int, long-integer

What is the  preferred way of defining a long integer in C? Are there any compatibility concerns?

```
long int ln;
```

or

```
long ln;
```

Comment: Note: The C11 spec consistently uses `long int` as in `long int ftell(FILE *stream);`.  I'd comply with the group's coding standard, if it exist, before my own preference (which in `long`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no "compatibility concerns", no. They are the exact same type, `long` is a short form of the type name `long int`. Just like `short` is a short form of `short int`.

It's of course very subjective, but I think most C programmers just use `long`.

Comment: Great, I personally like the long int definition, but I think I'll be using the shorter definition to save a few chars. Thanks.

Comment: It's all about readability, which matters little in this case.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between long and long int. You can use what you want. I would rather use long int to remember what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @unwind's answer, there is also `long double` and of course `long long int`.  Long might be useful in other rare corners of implementations (`long char`?) but it is *always* a modifier, but `int` is assumed if there is nothing to modify.

C's syntax has traditionally implied `int` in many places:

```
myfunction (i, j)
{
     return 6 * i + j;
}
```

In 1979 implementations on V6 Unix, `myfunction()` would be interpreted to return type `int` and both parameters would also be assumed to be `int` unless further declared:

```
float myfunction (i, j)
 long i;  float j;
{
     return 6 * i + j;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to mention also `signed long` and `signed long int`:)

According to the C Standard

> 5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type,
>   except that for bitfields, it is implementation-defined whether the
>   specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type
>   as unsigned int

So only for bitfields there is a difference between for example `int` and `signed int`

Take into account that you may write for example the following way

```
const signed const long const int ln;
```

It is equivalent to

```
const long ln;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the company you work for has coding conventions, and they include a requirement on this, you should follow the convention.  However, if there is no rule on how you should declare a `long int`, choose whatever seems best to you.

May I suggest though you use types defined in `stdint`.  For example, `long int` may be equivalent to `int32_t`.  In a lot of cases its useful to know the bit-width of the variables you're using.